Autodesk Construction Cloud: Autodesk API to bridge/share files from one ACC to another
Is there an API available to share an item from one project to another within the same Autodesk Construction Cloud, or to share it with a project in a different Autodesk Construction Cloud?
I have a file in one project that I want to use the Autodesk endpoint within a Workato recipe to move to another project in same/different ACC. Profiling the network calls, I see POST calls to 2 endpoints (neither are documented / publicly available APS endpoint)

POST call to https://api.segment.io/v1/t (no authorizationinvolved)
POST call to https://io.app.plangrid.com/proxy/bridge/v1/file-package (Auth token is being passed).


I was primarily trying to do the bridging of items from one project to another via Workato automation tool. My initial thought was I had to make a REST API call to Autodesk inorder to achieve this. But I found out that Workato Autodesk Cloud Connector, has a handy option to Upload document in a target project/folder and Download document from a target project/folder. That solves my problem.

